# Changing Bool Value from checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a bool called sendDataAuth. This bool is set to true on load. I have a checkbox which is in a checked state as default, on load.

I am trying to get this bool value to change to false if unchecked and back to true if checked again.

I have tried to create a if statement. If the checkbox state is changed, change the value of the bool.

```
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        sendDataAuth = true;
    }
    else
    {
        sendDataAuth = false;
    }
}
```

The bool remains true and never changes.

Comment: Do you have set the variable to true in the Page_Load event after checking if the Page_Load is called as a postback event? Or do you set the Checked state of the Checkbox in the Page_Load event?

Comment: Have you tried debugging step by step your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of you are using **C# Winform**

The simple way to change the value of sendDataAuth to the value of the checkbox is :

```
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sendDataAuth = checkBox1.Checked;
}
```

In the case of you are using **C# WPF**

There may be a misunderstanding between Checked and IsChecked.

**Checked** is an action that is called when there is a click on the CheckBox.

**IsChecked** is its value (a boolean)

So if you want to modify the value of sendDataAuth you can bind this value to IsChecked of your Checkbox or if you continue with your actual method do this :

```
private void CheckBox1_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sendDataAuth = CheckBox1.IsChecked ?? false;
}
```

Comment: Assuming a WPF application of course. But in that case can he compile its example?

Comment: @Steve Yes it's a WPF answer, the code in the question can't compile in WPF (i don't know if it work in winform ?)

Comment: Legends. Thanks. Sorry was a winform. Checked the code to

 private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sendDataAuth = checkBox1.Checked;
}

Comment: @ChrisBirch does it work now after you changed the code to `sendDataAuth = checkBox1.Checked;` ?

Comment: wouldn't WPF have `RoutedEventArgs`  in the event parameters? as opposed to `EventArgs` ?

Comment: I am confused here. How is this even possible to solve the problem, by changing the code to something that does exactly the same thing, but now it is apparently working?=!  Also since we know now, that it is winforms. Wouldn't it be appropriate to adopt the answer? "In the case of you are using C# WPF" it is technically not the appropriate answer.

Comment: sendDataAuth = checkBox1.Checked seems to be a neat why of doing what I was. Must admit I did find something that was changing the bool back again.

Im owning up to that. - Thanks everyone of their help though

Comment: "Must admit I did find something that was changing the bool back again." I shouldn't have removed my first comment ;) sorry mates but in my oppinion this post is not coherent in itself anymore. 1) the problem is not reproducible by teh given information in the post, and the accpected answer does not provide any solution. I think this post should be deleted

Comment: Mong Zhu Thanks for you feedback.

@TimSchmelter. The checkbox was just for testing purpose and will be deleted shortly and recreated properly

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know :) This was just a dirty test on a new winform till its implemented in my code :)